# Why my colored icon doesn't show in navigation drawer

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components, android-navigationview

I am making an Android app. I have used the side navigation drawer in it, I have not seen the color icons in the drawer, but i used color icons

[image]

My XML code is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/background_pic"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You're setting the `app:iconTint` to `@null`. You want to set the `iconTint` to the color you want the icons to be.

Comment: my icons are multi colored then what should i do ?

Comment: What are the views that you are using to populate the `NavigationView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null)
```

or in your layout use **`app:itemIconTint`** instead of `app:iconTint`

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemIconTint="@null"
```

Answer (score 1):

error in

```
app:iconTint="@null"
```

Use the `color` name/code you want to use
use it

```
app:itemIconTint="@null"
```

if you are using SVG

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(
    DrawableCompat.wrap(myImageView.getDrawable()),
    ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.another_nice_color)
);
```

[Change the color of drawable asset programmatically](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-change-colour-of-drawable-asset-programmatically-with-animation-e42ca595fabb)

Comment: brother i want to use multi color icon if i use "black" instead of "null" then whole icon filled with black color

Comment: android:tint="@android:color/white"  or you can use https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=clear&style=baseline for better icons